# how to conditionally order by two different categories from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables joined together. Two of the tables ("posts" and "shared_posts") have date categories. I want to order by date, but if `shared_posts.username = $username` I want it to use the shared_posts.date instead of posts.date. (and vice-versa)

I'm not sure how to do that. Here's what I have so far...

```
SELECT postid, posts.date, shared_posts.date, posts.username, posts.title
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN posts_views_likes USING (postid) 
LEFT JOIN shared_posts USING (postid) 
WHERE posts.username = '" . $username . "'
OR shared_posts.username = '" . $username . "'
ORDER BY posts.date DESC, shared_posts.date DESC
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN shared_posts.username = '" . $username ."'
    THEN shared_posts.date
    ELSE posts.date
  END DESC
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to be working. I get this error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN shared_posts.date ELSE posts.date END DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, forgot a `WHEN` - can you try again?

Comment: That did it! Thanks! :)